# Does Zend_Rest_Client support traditional object API work e.g. PUT an object, GET and object, POST an object

Tags: zend-framework, rest, zend-rest, zend-rest-route

I need to know if we can use Zend Framework to power a REST API?

Does Zend_Rest_Client support traditional object API work e.g.

PUT an object, GET and object, POST an object

Most REST API's I've seen have mostly been oriented around object management and not services or methods.

The help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from the reference manual that I hope answers your question. (The short answers is yes.)

> 24.5.7.6. Zend_Rest_Route The Zend_Rest component contains a RESTful route for Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite. This route offers a
>   standardized routing scheme that routes requests by translating the
>   HTTP method and the URI to a module, controller, and action. The table
>   below provides an overview of how request methods and URI's are
>   routed.
>
> Table 24.1. Zend_Rest_Route Behavior

```
Method URI Module_Controller::action 
GET /product/ratings/ Product_RatingsController::indexAction() 
GET /product/ratings/:id Product_RatingsController::getAction() 
POST /product/ratings Product_RatingsController::postAction() 
PUT /product/ratings/:id Product_RatingsController::putAction() 
DELETE /product/ratings/:id Product_RatingsController::deleteAction()  
POST /product/ratings/:id?_method=PUT Product_RatingsController::putAction() 
POST /product/ratings/:id?_method=DELETE Product_RatingsController::deleteAction()
```

and from the [Zend_Rest_Client API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/)

```
restDelete( string $path,  $data = null ) : \Zend_Http_Response
Performs an HTTP DELETE request to $path.


restGet( string $path, array $query = null ) : \Zend_Http_Response
Performs an HTTP GET request to the $path.


restPost( string $path, mixed $data = null ) : \Zend_Http_Response
Performs an HTTP POST request to $path.


restPut( string $path, mixed $data = null ) : \Zend_Http_Response
Performs an HTTP PUT request to $path.
```